# Qt/C++ linkage error (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, qt

I have troubles when I'm trying to make a linkage with static C/C++ library. Using QtCreator 2.7.2/Qt4.8/RHEL6. Here .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui widgets
DESTDIR = ../bin

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../bin/ -lsip
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../sip/include

TARGET = sipgui
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
....

HEADERS  += \
connectionpool.h \
....

FORMS    += dialog.ui

unix|win32: LIBS += -lcurses
```

When I'm calling library method from my project, i get "undefined reference" compilation error:

```
thread.o: In function `print_last_stats':
/home/virtual/Project/sip/build-sipgui-Desktop-Debug/../sipgui/thread.cpp:61: undefined           reference to `print_statistics'
....
/home/virtual/Project/sip/build-sipgui-Desktop-Debug/../sipgui/thread.cpp:64: undefined        reference to `print_statistics'
/home/virtual/Project/sip/sipgui/../bin//libsip.a(sipp-scenario.o): In function `scenario::parseAction(CActions*)':
/home/virtual/Desktop/sipp-3.4.1/sipp-3.4.1/src/scenario.cpp:1627: undefined reference to `hasMedia'
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you edit the .pro file, you must update the makefile too. Try [Build->clean All] -> [Build->Run qmake] -> [Build -> Rebuild All] to rebuild your project.

Comment: @Tay2510 I've tried, no effect.

Comment: It looks just like the library cannot be found for linking. Is the library really located at the givven path? evtl. you will need to traverse upwards once more from build directory?

Comment: @sebastian-lange Yes, it is located at given path. My build directory is: ../sip/sipgui, working directory is : ../sip/bin and libsip.a is located here.

Comment: Seems like my problem not in linkage, but in library file. I've tried to connect project with different library from this path, and it's compiled without any errors.

Comment: Maybe the library you tried to link was c library. In this case you will need add to your project: QMAKE_CC = g++
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c++11. Do you know where print_statistics is defined?